# IBM DB2: SQL subtraction doesn't work in denominator

Tags: sql, db2, subtraction, negative-number

I am working with manufacturing costs and the value of the fabrication still left to go (the "Net Work In Process"). The SQL is straight arithmetic but the query doesn't result in a value if there is a minus sign (subtraction) in the denominator. The database columns:

```
A = Material issued cost
B = Miscellaneous cost adds 
C = Labor
D = Overhead
E = Setup cost
F = Scrap cost
G = Received cost (cost of assemblies completed already)

H = Original Quantity ordered
I = Quantity deviation
J = Quantity split from order
K = Quantity received (number of assemblies completed already)
```

The Net WIP cost is nothing more than the total cost remaining divided by the total quantity remaining. So in short, I'm simply trying to do this:

```
select (A + B + C + D + E - F - G) / (H + I - J - K) from MyTable
```

The subtractions work fine in the numerator but as soon as I subtract in the denominator, the query simply returns no value (blank). I've tried stuff like this:

```
select (A + B + C + D + E - F - G) / (H + I - (J + K)) from MyTable
select (A + B + C + D + E - F - G) / (H + I + (-J) + (-K)) from MyTable
select (A + B + C + D + E - F - G) / (H + I + (J * -1) + (K * -1)) from MyTable
```

None of these work. Just curious if anyone has come across this on IBM's DB2 database?
Thanks.

Comment: show the data, `Select a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,  (A + B + C + D + E - F - G) / (H + I - (J + K)) as calc from MyTable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nulls in one of the columns `H`, `I`, `J`, or `K`. Search for the offending rows using:

```
select H, I, J, K
from MyTable
where H is null
   or I is null
   or J is null
   or K is null;
```

Then, you can treat those special cases according you your own logic. Typically you'll replace those nulls with zeroes or other values using `COALESCE()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are returning "blank" in a numeric calculation, then you have a `NULL` value somewhere.  Try using `coalesce()`:

```
nullif(coalesce(H, 0) + coalesce(I, 0) - coalesce(J, 0) - coalesce(K, 0), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks but says "COALESCE" is not a valid token. Maybe that's only SQL server. This is DB2

Comment: Can you use ```NVL``` or some other ```NULL``` value condition to avoid divide by ```NULL``` or 0 ?

Comment: @JohnJoseph . . . `COALESCE()` is a standard SQL function that DB2 supports (https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000780.html).  To avoid divide by zero, use `NULLIF()`.

Comment: @JohnJoseph `COALESCE()` is perfectly valid in DB2. See running example at: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=989e543f8df74847bff093b194131d6d

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your comments. I did scour the columns for NULLs and there aren't any. There are then plenty of conditions where, let's say, the factory sets the order to 10 and completes (receives) 10 with no splits and no deviation. In that case:

H + I + J + K = 0  (+10 +0 -0 -10) = 0

and I can't divide by zero. So I have a different workaround for that and thanks for everyone's help.